# Dynamically Added Input Box isn't dynamically binded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input

I'm using the Jquery Input modernizer function called on document.ready from this link:
http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-html5-placeholder-text

In my JavaScript code, I am adding 2 INPUT boxes to the DOM.  How can I dynamically bind these input objects so that they exhibit the same functionality as an input box that existed when the document was ready.

```
var add= '<input type="text" size="75" placeholder="This is a Comment" id="txtComment" />'
+ '<br /><input type="text" placeholder="2012-03-24" id="txtDate" /><br /><button id="submit">Submit</button>';

$(this).html(addTargetForm);


function modernizer_init() {
    if (!Modernizr.input.placeholder) {

        $('[placeholder]').onfocus(function () {
            var input = $(this);
            if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                input.val('');
                input.removeClass('placeholder');
            }
        }).blur(function () {
            var input = $(this);
            if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                input.addClass('placeholder');
                input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
            }
        }).blur();
        $('[placeholder]').parents('form').submit(function () {
            $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function () {
                var input = $(this);
                if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                    input.val('');
                }
            })
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Please give the code that binds the original functionality.

Comment: Please post your binding code.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I havent been able to figure it out myself but I do sometimes notice that when I .bind() with jquery on a dynamically placed element sometimes bind() won't work, where as live() will. I know it has to do something with DOM interactions and whats watching what when. But if bind() doesn't work try live(). But I also agree with Eli, you should post the code you have thats "binding" your elements events to your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work directly inside a `$(function(){...})` structure but by all means put it in a `function modernizer_init() {}` if that's what your application needs.

javascript:

```
$("body").on('focusin', '[placeholder]', function(evt) {
    var $input = $(evt.target);
    if ($input.val() == $input.attr('placeholder')) {
        $input.val('');
        $input.removeClass('placeholder');
    }
}).on('focusout', '[placeholder]', function(evt) {
    var $input = $(evt.target);
    if ($input.val() == '' || $input.val() == $input.attr('placeholder')) {
        $input.addClass('placeholder');
        $input.val($input.attr('placeholder'));
    }
}).on('submit', 'form', function(evt) {
    var $form = $(evt.target);
    $form.find('[placeholder]').each(function() {
        var $input = $(this);
        if ($input.val() == $input.attr('placeholder')) {
            $input.val('');
        }
    });
});
$('[placeholder]').focusout();
```

This works by delegating the handling of focusin (focus) and focusout (blur) events to the document body (or a more local container if you like), which is the jQuery 1.7.1 way to effect the now deprecated `bind()`, `.live()` and `.delegate()`.

See it working : http://jsfiddle.net/wg2eX/2/